# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returns null in android

Tags: android

In my application I am converting base64 string to image.For that I initially converted base 64 file to byte array and later am trying to convert to images.
To convert to Images I am using the below code

```
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File("/data/data/com.ayansys.Base64trial");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    String nameFile="Images";
    try {

        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5;
        options.inDither = true; 
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);


        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                sdImageMainDirectory.toString() +"/" + nameFile + ".jpg");


        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                fileOutputStream);

        myImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
```

but am getting my image as null at

```
Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
```

Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just a hint: leave a blank line before and after your code to enable the correct code formatter

Comment: @Remmyabhavan hi, I am getting the same problem, could you suggest me

Answer (score 2):

decodeByteArray  will not convert base 64 encoding to byte array. You need to use Base64 to byte array converter first

Comment: Yes i am using that to convert byte array to bitmap images.But am getting null error.The Imagedata that i am passing is the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem.  I solved it by removing this part of the string:

"data:image/jpeg;base64,"